# I failed to use \newenvironment and \newcommand

Tags: macros, environments, pstricks

The following code snippet does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand\Left{-1}
\newcommand\Right{1}
\newcommand\Bottom{-1}
\newcommand\Top{1}

\newenvironment{\PsPicture}[1][]
{\begin{pspicture}[#1](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)\ignorespaces}
{\end{pspicture}}

\newcommand\GetCoordinates{(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)}

\begin{document}
\begin{PsPicture}[showgrid]
\end{PsPicture}

\newpage

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid]\GetCoordinates
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The code above is a simplified scenario that was extracted from my own document class. The idea is to avoid calling `(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)` such as in

1. `\pspicture(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)`
2. or `\psframe(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)`

My first attempt is creating a new environment to encapsulate `\pspicture`, it does not work.
The second attempt is creating a new command to return `(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)` so hopefully it can be passed to any PSTricks macros that need `(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)`, it does not work as well.

How to fix it?

---

To make it clearer, I add the following code snippet

```
\begin{PsPicture}[showgrid]
\psframe\GetCoordinates
\end{PsPicture}
```

that takes advantage of `\GetCoordinates` so I can save some keystrokes rather than typing `(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)` that is very tedious.

Comment: Please no "it does not work" statements. Always state which errors you get or what exactly is not how it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it doesn't really make sense to define such new environments/commands, they do not make things easier!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand\Left{-1}
\newcommand\Right{1}
\newcommand\Bottom{-1}
\newcommand\Top{1}

\newenvironment{PsPicture}[1][]
{\pspicture[#1](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)}
{\endpspicture}

\newcommand\GetCoordinates{(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)}

\begin{document}
\begin{PsPicture}[showgrid]
\end{PsPicture}

\bigskip
\expandafter\pspicture\GetCoordinates
\psgrid[style=gridstyle]
\endpspicture

%or
\def\Temp{\pspicture[showgrid]}
\expandafter\Temp\GetCoordinates
\endpspicture

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I have no idea about `\expandafter`, it is really a new macro that I must learn now. Thank you.

Comment: "Expand the token after the following command" Instead of `\pspicture\GetCoordinates` you get with `\expandafter` the correct syntax: `\pspicture(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)`

Comment: How to use `\exapandafter` when I need to use `[]` such as in `\expandafter\psframe[linecolor=red]\GetCoordinates`?

Comment: see edited example

Comment: +1 It makes more complicated. I should cancel this idea. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your first question: Your syntax for `\newenvironment` is wrong. Replace

```
\newenvironment{\PsPicture}[1][]
```

with

```
\newenvironment{PsPicture}[1][]
```

(without backslash).

Comment: Here's some more information on the [`\newcommand`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-18.html) and [`\newenvironment`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-19.html) definitions.

Comment: +1 for answering the first problem. How about the second one, `\GetCoordinates`?

Comment: @xport: I think Martin gave the correct answer to your second question, and because it was the harder one, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `pspicture` awaits the `( ... )` as part of its syntax and placing it inside a macro like `\GetCoordinates` hides it from it, which causes the issue. I would even expand the coordinates in the `PsPicture` environment first before passing it to `pstricks`, just to be on the save side.

```
\newenvironment{PsPicture}[1][]{%
\begingroup
\edef\@tempa{(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)}%
\def\@tempb{\endgroup\begin{pspicture}[#1]}%
\expandafter\@tempb\@tempa
\ignorespaces}
{\end{pspicture}}
```